# simulink run with gui matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, simulink

i have a Gui and a Simulink Model, i wanna enter some value into the textfield in the Gui and press start Button and after this, my simulink model should take these values and run, the result should be displayed in the gui statictext.

to simulink: i have to constant blocks, thes name ist kraft and flaeche. and the oarameter into the blocks are k and f.

ok now i want to edit the values of k and f in the gui. This is my code:

```
      function kraft_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
      kraft_value = str2num(get(hObject,'String')); 
     if (isempty(kraft_value)) 
     set(hObject,'String','0') 
     end 
      guidata(hObject, handles); 

     function flaeche_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     flaeche_value = str2num(get(hObject,'String')); 
     if (isempty(flaeche_value)) 
     set(hObject,'String','0') 
      end 
     guidata(hObject, handles);

     function start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     k= str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
     f= str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
     sim('Steifigkeit');


    function static_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

But i get these Errors :

```
     Error using Gui>start_Callback (line 215)
      Error due to multiple causes.

    Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
    feval(varargin{:});

      Error in Gui (line 17)
     gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

        Error in                     @(hObject,eventdata)Gui('start_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


      Caused by:
     Error using Gui>start_Callback (line 215)
    Error evaluating parameter 'Value' in 'Steifigkeit/f'
    Error using Gui>start_Callback (line 215)
    Undefined function or variable 'f'.
    Error using Gui>start_Callback (line 215)
    Error evaluating parameter 'Value' in 'Steifigkeit/k'
    Error using Gui>start_Callback (line 215)
    Undefined function or variable 'k'.
```

can somebody help me

Answer (score 1):

I think Simulink is looking for `k` and `f` in the base workspace, but they are only defined in your callback function workspace. You probably need to use [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html):

```
function start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
k= str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
f= str2double(get(hObject,'string'));
assignin('base','f',f);
assignin('base','k',k);
sim('Steifigkeit');
```

I don't know how your GUI is constructed, but to me it looks like k and f are the same based on your code. Is this how you meant it to be?

Comment: k and f are not the same, k is the constant value of one constant_block and f is the constant value of another constant_block.
i want to enter the value of those constant_values in the GUI and after this, the simulink model should run and the result of those values should be displayed in the GUI again, in a Static_textfield.

Comment: I would upload a picture of my gui and Simulink but my reputation ist not high enough. :)

Comment: Your GUI code makes `k` and `f` the same values as far as I can tell: you get the `string` property from the same object and convert it to double.

Comment: yes, but meanwhile i use this :

           k = str2double(get(handles.kraft,'String'));
           f = str2double(get(handles.flaeche,'String'));

Comment: yes, I get now 3 warnnings :)... But the result deos not displayed in the gui how wanted.
in the simulink model, I incuded afte the divide_block a To workSpace_block to take the result of divide Operation and to display it in the Gui. But it deosnot work.

Comment: For the same reason... The To Workspace block writes data in the base workspace (accessible once the simulation is finished). You need to use `evalin` to retrieve the data from the base workspace and make it available to your local function workspace.

Comment: or you can use the syntax:
`[timeVector,stateVector,outputVector] = sim(<your_model_name>)`
which would make the simulation outputs directly available in your callback function workspace (provided you have used `outport` blocks for the relevant outputs of your model). See the following in the doc:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/a-gui-to-set-simulink-model-parameters-guide.html

Comment: you mean like this:
assignin('base','k',k);
k = evalin('base','k');

Comment: It depends what's in your To Workspace block and what you want to display in your GUI. Basically, any signal that feeds to an outport block at the top level of your model will be in the output vector returned by the `sim` function.

Comment: I am trying with your example(Link) ist is good by when i use the second slider i get this Error: Error using Gui>flaecheSlider_Callback (line 299)
Gain block does not have a parameter named 'f'
But i make the same things for the first slider and it works. i use for each slider a gain-Block. Maybe that is the problem????

Comment: It all depends on how your slider blocks are parameterised and how you access them from your code. You really need to familiarise yourself with command line functions for Simulink to access block and model parameters, as well as with the different types of workspace (base, caller, etc...) and where your data reside.

Answer (score 0):

The general form of the command syntax for running a simulation is:

```
SimOut = sim('model', Parameters)
```

So this way you can run simulink models from anywhere using commands. you can also add your parameters to the model and run it.

The following example shows how to create a configuration set and use it with the sim syntax.

```
model = 'vdp';
load_system(model)
simMode = get_param(model, 'SimulationMode');
set_param(model, 'SimulationMode', 'rapid')
cs = getActiveConfigSet(model);
model_cs = cs.copy;
set_param(model_cs,'AbsTol','1e-5',...
         'SaveState','on','StateSaveName','xoutNew',...
         'SaveOutput','on','OutputSaveName','youtNew')
simOut = sim(model, model_cs);
set_param(model, 'SimulationMode', simMode)
```

so you just need to replace the values from textbox and that would be this...

I usually use this to set a value in simulink:

```
Control_Gains(1,1)=str2double(get_param([ModelName,'/PID1/PIDx'],'P'));
```

or:

```
NewString               =   ['[',(num2str(KT)),']'];
set_param([ModelName,'/System/Model/Gain'],'Gain',NewString);
```

Comment: thank for the answare, but i can not do anything with it.  should I write this in the callback function??? and in my case is the vdp = Steifigkeit????? and the rapid = k ???? or what is the meaning of these Parameters ?

Comment: vdp is the name of the simulink and you can replace it with yours. If you check the last two commands, you see that I am using the parameter 'KT', convert it to string, and pass it to my simulink. So I can change values of parameters in my simulink from command line. and most command line commands you can use in your gui...

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code but there seems to be no function that will update the constant blocks.. I have created a similar GUI to tune inputs at runtime. 
Try this approach:

In the *callbacks of your editboxes* in the GUI, write these commands

```
valstr=get(hObject,'String');
val=str2double(valstr);
assignin('base','nameofvariableinmatlabworkspace',val);
set_param('constantblockpath','Value','nameofvariableinmatlabworkspace');
```

Replace nameofvariableinmatlabworkspace with the name of the variable that appears inside the constant blocks whose value should change according to the value entered in the GUI.
Replace constantblockpath with the path to that constant block e.g. mymodel/Constant12

You might want to do some data validation for the editboxes as well, before assigning their values in the matlab workspace variables.